# Can anyone help with paramaterization of conics?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, algebraic-curves, parametrization

Im struggling to wrap my head around an example. It considers the conic $$
x^{2}+y^{2}-z^{2}=0
$$ then proceeds:

Take $A=[1,0,1]$ and the line $P(U)$ defined by $x=0$. Note that this conic and the point and line are defined over any field since the coefficients are 0 or $1 .$
A point $X \in P(U)$ is of the form $X=[0,1, t]$ or $[0,0,1]$ and the map $\alpha$ is

\begin{align}
\alpha([0,1, t]) &=[B((0,1, t),(0,1, t))(1,0,1)-2 B((1,0,1),(0,1, t))(0,1, t)]
\\ &=\left[1-t^{2}, 2 t, 1+t^{2}\right]
\\ \text { or } \alpha([0,0,1])=[-1,0,1] .
\end{align}

How do I evaluate $B(v,v)$ or $B(v,v)(a,b,c)$ like they have to go from the first line to the second?

and also why is a point $X \in P(U)$ of the form $X=[0,1, t]$ or $[0,0,1]$

here is the source for reference:https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/files/LectureNotes/Algebraic_curves/algebraiccurves2009.pdf

any help would be fantastic!

Comment: You need to copy the main definitions so that we do not have to read the whole notes. To begin with, you have to mention that you are working in projective spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, it is exactly evaluation of a bilinear form, given by the matrix B, on the given vectors: so $B(v,w)=v^tBw$.
This gives you a scalar which is understood multipling the following vector.

For the second one, when you have a projective line $l$ and two dinstinct points $P,Q$ on it then every other point can be written as $\lambda P+\mu Q$, for $[\lambda,\mu]\in\mathbb{P}^1$.
So you can define $t=\mu/\lambda$, if $\lambda\neq 0$, and consider $l$ as the points in the form $ P+tQ$ union the remaining point corresponding to $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: How do you find the matrix B? I thought B defined the conic $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$? I can’t figure out how to evaluate B(v,v) especially since the y value for the second line is linear yet the conic has all quadratic terms

Comment: Exactly, B is the matrix defining the conic.